# How to synchronize SQLite database with server?

Tags: android, sql-server, synchronization, android-sqlite

I have created a SQLite database in my android app. I want the data of every user in a centralized database. How can i setup the server and the sychronization that will allow me to get the data from every user?
What are the steps that need to be followed ?

Answer (score 1):

Data synchronization is very complicated process. In document above there are some sample patterns which you may use.

http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/PDF/PatternPaperv11.pdf

You need to know what kind of troubles you can meet and include solutions for them in your project.

E.g.

`User1` and `User2` have synchronized data. `User1` is modyfying one row in table `Data`. In the same time `User2` has deleted this row. Your job is to handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

I guess replication is what you are looking for.

> Replication is a set of technologies for copying and distributing data and database objects from one database to another and then synchronizing between databases to maintain consistency. Using replication, you can distribute data to different locations and to remote or mobile users over local and wide area networks, dial-up connections, wireless connections, and the Internet.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/ms151198.aspx

Comment: It seems like this is the solution to my problem.
But can u tell me how replication can be performed?

Comment: Replication is not a process i can just tell. You need to make some research to find what you need. If you have questions you can ask on the site.